# Apply dark mode to old-style Win32 applications via Windows APIs by changing their colors

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, darkmode

I am trying to apply dark mode to the old-style Win32 applications. You know, run box, management console, old-style settings windows, etc.

I found out that you can use SetSysColors (winuser.h) to apply colors to the basic windows controls. However it seems like that is not really working fully. I assume it's because the API is quite old, and also that some applications are just not using the constants it changes.

That means that while this does work really well for example for the content of the Disk management window:

[image]

It completely fails at other things. That includes, as you can see, the title bars, as well as other parts of the UI in the same window.

Also, some windows don't work basically at all, like the run dialog:

[image]

How would I go about changing the colors of those other Windows/UI elements?
High contrast themes also work for example. Is there an API to hook into, or some registry keys to change?